# How do you set a Bixby reminder programmatically?

Tags: reminders, bixby

I'm working on a Bixby integration and I'm looking through the Bixby documentation and I have some marketing info on Bixby reminders, but I'm looking for how reminders can be created programmatically or via an API and I'm not finding any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting use case that would require some discussion with the Bixby team to fully address.

Due to this, I would recommend reaching out to the Bixby Developer Support team via the "Contact Support" option in the Help section of Bixby Developer Studio or the Support button at the top right of the [Bixby Developer documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/) home page so a member of our team can speak to you about your specific use case.